# How can I have a season achievement without the corresponding season's journey requirement?

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements

Case in point:

[image]
[image]

Anyone know what's happening here?

Comment: This one is weird sometimes.  Try logging out and logging back in again.

Comment: That did it! Weird :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This particular requirement seems to be buggy, and I had the same thing happen to me.  I resolved it by logging out and logging in again.  Upon entering the game, I was awarded with the Season's Journey progress.

Answer (score 1):

That achievement is buggy.

Same thing happened to me, but once I hit 100 extracts, all those achievements unlocked.